# Old Paper Stock Certificates Bought at Estate Auctio

Tags: securities

I found two very very old stock Certificates inside a book that I bought at an Estate Sale being sold by an Auction Company. I received a bill of sale from the auction company for the contents of the items I purchased which some came from inside the house and some came from a chicken house/building of the deceased individual and we just paid the auction company and loaded up all the boxes and things we bought and brought them to our home and when cleaning it out and going through it all I came across the two old stock certificates in a book  down inside one of the boxes, and so my question is would I have claim to them if they are still of value? And if so, how do I find that out? Do I need to contact someone within the State of Alabama which is where they’re registered and/or do I need to have anything else showing that I bought them and they are now in my possession other than the bill of sale/invoice that I received from the Auction Company which clearly states that items are being sold “From the Estate of ……….” to me and so in my opinion I am now the actual owner of these shares/certificates  but they still show the deceased mans name on the face of the certificate and so how do I get them transferred to my name or reissued in my name without him actually being here to sign and transfer them to me…. Please point me i the right direction as to what to do with them because I’m fairly certain the company (Vanguard) is still trading and active in the market but not sure as to which company to contact and or how to figure that out. But if I’m figuring correctly then they are worth ALOT of money not to mention that they are from 1969 and 1970 which could make them even more valuable if the stock split any number of times over the years and or they reinvested dividends and etc.

Comment: We don't do legal advice here, sorry.  Especially don't ask people to contact you off-site.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same "Vanguard" company? If your stock is from 69/70 I'd be concerned, Vanguard (the mutual fund company) started in 1975.

Comment: The mutual fund company by that name that @RonBeyer mentions _also_ has a very unusual corporate structure, and it doesn't have "stockholders" in the traditional sense.

Comment: Maybe move to money.stackexhange as there once was a "scripophily" tag there, and "are old shares worth anything" is a scripophily question.

Comment: But, before you post there - if you want anyone to actually read your question - format it.
 That huge, monolithic,  block of text hurts my eyes.